# Access odd indexes of a byte array causes address error

Tags: assembly, 68000

I have an array of bytes in my code and i have to access random elements of this array.
Address of array is loaded in `A4` and the index is calculated and stored in `D2`. I need to read one element (one byte) from this array in index of `D2` and add it to D7. Let me make that more clear by showing how it is implemented in C language:

```
char Array[80];
char* A4 = Array; // Equivalent to &Array[0]

short D2, D7 = 0;

for(...) {
   D2 = ...
   D7 += A4[D2];
}
```

How i implemented it in m68k assembly(A part of code):

```
lea Array, A4
clr.l D7

* for (...) {
* D2 = ...
add.w (A4,D2),D7      ; D7 += A4[D2]; 
* }

ORG $2000
Array ds.b 80
```

But sometimes D2 is odd and `A4 + D2` is an odd Address so simulator produces Address Error, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are reading a word from array not a byte, changing 6th line of assembly code to this:

```
add.b (A4,D2), D7
```

will fix the problem.

Comment: Why do you talk in second person with yourself? :O

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix It's like somebody else is answering :D